# How to use AWS Iot to transfer realtime stock info?

Tags: aws-iot

For example,I have 1000 users,their watchlists have different stocks,how to use AWS Iot to transfer different info to different users?I use Springboot for my server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that AWS IoT is the right service for what you are trying to do. The AWS documentation [1] describes the service as following:

> AWS IoT provides secure, bi-directional communication between Internet-connected devices such as sensors, actuators, embedded micro-controllers, or smart appliances and the AWS Cloud. This enables you to collect telemetry data from multiple devices, and store and analyze the data. You can also create applications that enable your users to control these devices from their phones or tablets.

The pricing might be high to transfer stock data back and forth via IoT messaging. [2]
That depends on the time interval in which data is sent to the users.

You should provide far more info about your use case in order for the community to assess whether AWS IoT is the right service or AWS AppSync [3] is better suited. When it turns out that IoT is the right choice, I can elaborate on how to structure the IoT topics etc.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html
[2] https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/pricing/?nc1=h_ls
[3] https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/resources/?nc1=h_ls